# What should be the bucket path for nested term aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do pipeline aggregation on my elasticsearch aggregation. Here is my query body

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "user_info": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "product_info": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_item_price": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "selling_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "price_percentile": {
      "percentiles_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "user_info.product_info.total_item_price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is giving me error that 
`No aggregation found for path [user_info.product_info.total_item_price]`
What should be the path for bucket if such nested aggregation is there? Or is it not possible to find percentiles for such bucket arrangement in elasticsearch.

**P.S I am using elasticsearch 6.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jzzfs answer is also somewhat right. I approached it in a different way. I reversed my aggregations and it fulfilled my use case. But in general, you can't do nested bucket percentiles for now.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "product_info": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_info": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_item_price": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "selling_price"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "pb": {
          "percentiles_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "user_info>total_item_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use dots in the path -- use `>` instead:

```
GET stack/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "user_info": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "product_info": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_item_price": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "selling_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pb": {
      "percentiles_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "user_info>product_info>total_item_price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which yields `"buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Object[]] at aggregation [product_info]"` so it's not gonna work.

---

Here are our options:

1. Aggregate globally but just under the bucketed product info (without the users):

```
GET stack/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "product_info": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_item_price": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "selling_price"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "pb": {
      "percentiles_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "product_info>total_item_price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use filtered aggregations in order to mimic the original intent:

```
GET stack/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "user_123": {                        <-- keeping the agg name consistent w/ the filter
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "user_id": 123                 <-- actual filter
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "product_info": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "product_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_item_price": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "selling_price"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "pb": {
          "percentiles_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "product_info>total_item_price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then have as many `user_xyz` subaggregations as you like -- provided you gather their IDs beforehand.

Comment: in first cases that aggregation will not be user_specific and in the second one there will be many subaggregations when we will scale. but still, ideas are cool.

Comment: How many users do you need to analyze, really? :) If you're interested in top 10 buyers, you'd aggregate by the sum of their products' `selling_price`s and then do this percentile analysis... I can't think of a use case where you'd _have_ to do it on the top, user level.